# What's the difference between "the mechanics" and "the mechanism"

Tags: differences

***the mechanics [plural]***  {**the way something works or is done**}

The exact mechanics of how payment will be made will be decided later.

***mechanism***  {**a method or a system for achieving something**}

mechanisms for dealing with complaints from the general public

The college has established an effective student support mechanism.

Comment: "The mechanics", when not speaking of the guys standing there in grease-stained clothes holding wrenches, refers to the logical operation of the "thing".  "The mechanism" refers to the specific gears and pulleys and whatnot of a specific realization.  There is some overlap, however.

Answer (score 1):

**mechanics (3)**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mechanics?s=t

The technical aspect of pretty much anything

**mechanism (2)**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mechanism

the agency or means by which an effect is produced or a purpose is accomplished.

They are interchangeable (sort of) in this particular case.

The mechanics (of something) is a more general term. Aspects may be added or subtracted. Your first example is telling: "the exact mechanics [...] will be *decided* later."

The mechanism for something is normally a single system, an algorithm for accomplishing something. It can't be *decided*: it needs to be *developed*.

Answer (score 0):

All your examples are grammatically correct.

Your question title *could* read "What's the difference between "the mechanics **of**" and "the mechanics **for**."

In either case, the intended meaning is clear.